# ManyToMany Data in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

If I have ManyToMany Relationship from Model A to Model B and edit the data in Model B, will it change the data in Model A?

For Instance:

```
class Section(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()


class Document(models.Model):
    sections = models.ManyToManyField(Section)
```

Sections are created, and then a Document is created from one or more of those sections.  In the Document database, are the sections copies of the original sections or are they placeholders to the original sections?  And so, if a user edits the newly created document, and therefore the sections in it, will they edit the original sections?

Comment: Yes, if you modify one of the sections in Document model and save it (save the section object), the Section object in database will change.

Comment: Right, that's what I suspected. What methods are there for making a copy of the data?

Comment: If you want modify the data without changing the original object, that is not a _relationship_

Comment: Oh, ok, so instead of a M2M field I could save a copy of the data in Sections in a Document object?

Comment: Yep. Or maybe use a custom intermediate table and save the change history there. See [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)